# CS50(2021) Filter - Blur

Tags: c, cs50, blur

I couldn't figure out why the blur doesn't work when I check with check50. The image becomes blurry, but the RGB values are wrong. I'm not sure what I did wrong. If anyone knows, please do tell.

This is the picture of my
[results in check50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JRbB.png).

This is my code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    // Copy image
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
        }
    }


    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            int row[] = { h - 1, h, h + 1 };
            int col[] = { w - 1, w, w + 1 };

            int R = 0;
            int G = 0;
            int B = 0;
            int num = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                // Check whether they are in frame
                if (row[x] < 0 || row[x] >= height)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (col[x] < 0 || col[x] >= width)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            
                // Add up the value
                R += copy[row[x]][col[x]].rgbtRed;
                G += copy[row[x]][col[x]].rgbtGreen;
                B += copy[row[x]][col[x]].rgbtBlue;
                num++;
            }
        
            // Average
            int blurRed = round(R / num);
            int blurGreen = round(G / num);
            int blurBlue = round(B / num);
        
            // Update pixel
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = blurRed;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = blurGreen;
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = blurBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need a double nested loop for `x` ***and*** `y`. The code only averages 3 pixels, not 9.

Comment: Aside: `R / num` etc do integer division and truncate the result, so `round()` has no effect.

Comment: The Check50 message contains a complete set of data that is used for the failing test. You should prepare test wrapper for your function that feeds in exactly that data and step through it in a debugger to check all values in each instruction. That

Comment: Please also read the description of the tags you add to your question. The `filter` tag is used for restricting access to data, not for graphics manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your responses and clarifications. I added the nested loop and changed the values to float, so it worked now. I'll keep the tag description in mind if I would post next time, and I'll definitely use the values to check with debugger50. Awesome tip! Thanks again!